# How to split a file into parts based on a template?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, text, split

I am looking at analyzing text files which have a known structure. Before going into a Rube-Goldberg-machine kind of solution I wanted to check if there was a standard approach to such problems.

The file structure is

```
whatever text, empty lines more text

long text empty lines
whatever
← one empty line
line 1 of final block of text
line 2 of final block of text
line 3 of final block of text
← more lines, the number is not defined
← new line and end of file
```

So this is free text until an empty line, then a block of single lines of text without empty lines and the end of file on an new line.

I would like to split that file into the two main parts: the free text par and the block part. Both will then be analyzed independently.

My first hope is that there would be some kind of "file pattern matching" module, where I would describe the file similarly to the way above and retrieve my two parts. I just found templating (which is the other way round: describe the contents of a file in order to create it).

**The next solution which comes to mind is regex. The part I am struggling with is to describe "a block of text with only single line returns". How could that be described?**

And generally - **is there a simpler solution to that problem?** (just pointing to that would be great, it is likely that I simply never met that approach).

My gut feeling is that the file should be analyzed from bottom to the top - this is probably the solution I will be developing if there is no more obvious one.

Comment: Frankly, I do not understand the problem. You write "then a block of one lines of text without empty lines " - what is a "block of one lines"?! How do you recognize that a fragment of file is "a block"?

Comment: @Błotosmętek: a block of one ("single" would be better) lines" are lines which are not divided by one or more empty lines. In other word only a single line separator is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
>>> a = '''whatever text, empty lines more text
... 
... long text empty lines
... whatever
... ← one empty line
... line 1 of final block of text
... line 2 of final block of text
... line 3 of final block of text
... ← more lines, the number is not defined
... ← new line and end of file
... '''
>>> a.rsplit('\n\n', 1)
['whatever text, empty lines more text', 'long text empty lines\nwhatever\n\xe2\x86\x90 one empty line\nline 1 of final block of text\nline 2 of final block of text\nline 3 of final block of text\n\xe2\x86\x90 more lines, the number is not defined\n\xe2\x86\x90 new line and end of file\n']
>>>
```

Comment: Ah, this is an excellent idea - splitting on `\n\n` and `.pop(-1)` gives me the block, leaving the freetext to analyze. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @WoJ made small change: `.rsplit( ..., 1)` will make sure you get exactly 2 blocks, don't have to use `[-1]`, just `[0]` and `[1]`